# Resource file doesn't show changes after manipulation by tomcat webservice

Tags: web-services, tomcat, intellij-idea, jaxb, jersey

I have a little tomcat webservice. In the resources directory I have a file, myresource.xml. I read from and write to that file using the webservice.

After writing something new to the file, I can imediatly read it, which is nice. But the file myresource.xml in the resources directory doesn't reflect that changes. If I restart the webservice from IDEA, the changes are still available, but when I for example restart my machine they are gone.

The myresource.xml contains a list of `Entity` objects, the list being `Entities`. To write to the file, I first unmarshal it, add a new `Entitiy` object to `Entities` and then marshal it.

The code looks like this:

```
 public static Entities unmarshalEntities() throws JAXBException, IOException {
        URL dataUrl = XmlUtils.class.getResource("/myresource.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = dataUrl.openStream();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entities.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Entities entities = (Entities) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        return entities;
    }



public static void marshalEntities(Entities entities) throws IOException, JAXBException, URISyntaxException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entities.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        URL url = XmlUtils.class.getResource("/myresource.xml");
        File file = new File(url.toURI());
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(entities, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

What do I have to change so that my changes are persisted into myresource.xml?

Comment: The source file will not get modified. When you build your app, the source file is copied into the folder where all the classes are. You can print out `S.o.p(file.getAbsolutePath())`. So when you write to the file, it will be this copied file that gets written to, not the original source file. Generally you should not write to classpath resources. You want to write to files accessed via the file system.